# How to get "breaking news" on custom ContextualWebSearch?

Tags: json, api, feed

I am using Contextual Web search REST API called Custom search.

https://rapidapi.com/contextualwebsearch/api/custom-search

Here I can 
search any news topic i like from the newssources i want. So far so good! But i now try to make a "home page" with breaking news, to get the latest articles in the world with politics, tech, finance etc.

```
apiClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-rapidapi-host", HostHeader);
apiClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-rapidapi-key", KeyHeader);

string searchterm = "Obama";
var responseMessage = await apiClient.GetAsync("https://custom-search.p.rapidapi.com/api/search/CustomWebSearchAPIV2?q=" + searchterm + "&searchEngineId=43212194233309&pageNumber=1");

var response = responseMessage.Content;
var json = await response.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Right now my code looks like this, and in this case the search term is "Obama". Articles loads in very nicely. But how would i adjust the search term to get breaking news? As this query is only limited to artciles regarding "Obama".

An idea i had was to perhaps make the searchterm something like: "politics-finance-tech-health". But unsure if this will give me the needed results.

Maybe someone with more experience with this rest API can share their knowledge!

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you search for something like "world news", or you create a tab view with each section being a popular category of news... eg, health, art, science, politics and you display the top news in those sections